# Install other apks silently

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

Is there a way to build an Android application that can download and install other apks silently without asking the user's permission to install them?

So far to download the apks is easy, the problem is when installing them as they require the user's approval to be installed.

So far I have tried the following code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(s)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivityForResult(intent, INSTALL_APK);
```

This asks for the user's approval to install the apk. 
Is there another way to do this without prompting the user?

Thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/how-to-install-a-application-in-background-on-android/) out

Comment: Can you explain your use case a bit more?

Comment: The first question to always ask, would you want an app to do this to you? Think of how malicious this could turn against your device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, without the user's permission there is no way an app can be installed to an android device except if it is connected for development with a computer.The User's privacy/permission policy as implemented by Google for app installation does not allow any app or device to install a fresh app w/o user's permission. However, frequent app upgrade can be done w/o user's permission.

Refer:
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/190930?hl=en

and

https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/2364439?hl=en

Note :- There are some mechanisms to install apks w/o user's permission provided the device is rooted.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I know that this is possible if the device is rooter, I was wondering if this is possible without.

Comment: @Ancuta Of course it's not. You can't just allow third party apps to download and install random software. That would be a security hole onpar with arbitrary code execution. The reason it works when the device is rooted is because rooting disables any and all of these security checks and not only makes your device vulnerable to this but many other attacks. Never root your device.

Comment: There is only one real thing this ability could be used for: malware. Any real use case doesn't need such dangerous abilities.

Comment: How is Amazon App Store able to update apps like Amazon Instant Video silently? Because it does that without a prompt

Comment: so if my device is not rooted, my only option is to publish it in google play to  implement an automatic update without showing any prompt?

Comment: @BenjaminG Exactly !! By default 'Automatic Update' is turned on in Android devices. So if you upload a new apk on playstore Users will get it updated automatically. However Users have the option to turn'Automatic Update' option off. In that case they have to manually update the app.

Answer (score 0):

try this answer from another developer (Palak) , Root required

```
public static void InstallAPK(String filename){
    File file = new File(filename); 
    if(file.exists()){
        try {   
            String command;
            command = "adb install -r " + filename;
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command });
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  }
```

he probably took is also from this link http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/how-to-install-a-application-in-background-on-android/

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid True, you can also install if the device is not rooted but you have to be device owner. So in general on non-rooted user devices it can't be done

Comment: I was wondering if this can be done without the device being rooter.

Comment: I have device admin app and this command goes in exception showing Environment=null